# Selecting a row from an array by elements of a subset

Tags: list-manipulation

Assume that

```
A = Permutations[{1, 2, 3}]
```

[image]

AND $$C=\{1,2\}$$
I want to apply this process
$X=C\subset A$
The output is
$$X=\{1,2,3\},\{2,1,3\}$$

How can the array row be selected according to the elements in the subset

My attempts

```
Select[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 
   1}}, MemberQ[1, 2, #] &]
```

The output is

[image]

```
a = Permutations[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}]; c = {2, 3, 4} Select[a, ContainsAll[#[[1 ;; 2 ;; 3]], c] &]
```

How can the answer be generalized?

Comment: Could you explain the operation you are doing? I don't understand how to arrive at the output you indicated.

Comment: My guess is that he is only checking the first two elements of each triple.

Comment: I need to checking the first two elements of each triple

Comment: @MarcoB I need to checking the first two elements of each triple

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
a = Permutations[{1, 2, 3}]
c = {1, 2}

Select[a, ContainsAll[#[[1 ;; 2]], c] &]

(* Out: {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 3}} *)
```

Comment: Many thanks for this valuable help: this is what I was looking for. I am grateful to you

Comment: a = Permutations[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}];
c = {2, 3, 4}

Select[a, ContainsAll[#[[1 ;; 2 ;; 3]], c] &]

How can the answer be generalized?

Comment: @Math-babylon To check the first three elements of the sets, you should use `ContainsAll[ #[[1;;3]], c]&` instead. Look up [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

**Using `SubsetQ`**:

```
a = Permutations[{1, 2, 3}];
c = {1, 2};

Pick[a, SubsetQ[#, c] & /@ a[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]
```

OR

```
Select[a, SubsetQ[#[[1 ;; 2]], c] &]
```

**Using `OrderlessPatternSequence`**:

```
Pick[a, MatchQ[#[[1 ;; 2]], {OrderlessPatternSequence[
      Sequence @@ c]}] & /@ a]
```

OR

```
Select[MatchQ[#[[1 ;; 2]], {OrderlessPatternSequence[
      Sequence @@ c]}] &][a]
```

---

Result:

> {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 3}}

Comment: a = Permutations[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}]; c = {2, 3, 4} How can the answer be generalized?

Comment: As an example: `Pick[a, SubsetQ[#, c] & /@ a[[All, 1 ;; Length@c]]]` would have 720 entries.